# How to connect outlook mail server which uses Multi factor authentication using java mail?

Tags: authentication, outlook, jakarta-mail, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to connect outlook mail through Java Mail API. My outlook account is Multi Factor Authenticated (MFA)using ping Identity.

I can generate a ping Id token as it mentioned [here](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/p1_saasAppsIntegrateApp_aps/page/samples/javaExchangeTokenSample.html).

Now my question is how can pass this token from Java mail Api to connect my outlook account ?

Debug Result:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.2

DEBUG: getProvider() returning

javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]

DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384

DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false

DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000

DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1

DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10

DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure

DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "imap-mail.outlook.com", port 993, isSSL true

* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.

[QwBPADIAUABSADAANgBDAEEAMAAwADUAOAAuAG4AYQBtAHAAcgBkADAANgAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBvAHUAC4AYwBvAG0A]

A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+

A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.

DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN

DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH2

DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=imap-mail.outlook.com,

user=jeethesh.karkera@compmail.com, password=<non-null>

DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command trace suppressed

DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command result: A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.

javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.

    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:732)

    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)

    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)

    at com.outlook.outlook.controller.TestController.mailDetails(TestController.java:54)
```

Comment: Is this anything like [OAuth2](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2)?  How does the mail server expect to receive the token using the IMAP protocol?  How would you configure Thunderbird to access Outlook using MFA?

Comment: @BillShannon Yeah it uses OAUTH2 token..
yeah I don't know how to configure Thunderbird to access Outlook. That's the reason I asked my question here expecting some help.

Comment: Did you try configuring JavaMail to use OAuth2 as described in the link I sent?

Comment: @BillShannon  Yeah tried but i'm getting "AUTHENTICATIONFAILED" exception.

Comment: Can you post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug)?  How are you obtaining the OAuth2 access token?  Are you encoding the token before using it with JavaMail?  (You shouldn't.)

Comment: @BillShannon I updated my debug result. I'm getting OAUTH2 token from following URL [link](https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net). Same token if I use in postman its working fine.

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem.  The access tokens typically expire after 1 hour.  Can you set the property `mail.debug.auth` to true and then post the (expired) access token you're using and the details from the debug output showing the authentication exchange?

Comment: @JEETHESHKARKERA I am also facing same issue, If u find any solution, Colud you please share ?

Comment: @Mihir Sorry I didn't find any solutions for that . Temporarily I have stopped that work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of auth token use app password for authentication. You can generate app password from Outlook - view account -> security.