# How to connect outlook mail server which uses Multi factor authentication using imaplib?

Tags: python

```
import imaplib

imap_host = 'imap-mail.outlook.com'
imap_user = ''
imap_pass = ''

imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host)
imap.login(imap_user, imap_pass)
imap.select('Inbox')
```

But it is showing error:-

**error:**

```
    imap.login(imap_user, imap_pass)
      File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\imaplib.py", line 612, in login
        raise self.error(dat[-1])
 imaplib.IMAP4.error: b'LOGIN failed.'
```

I have authentication code in my bitwarden credentials. Now my question is how can put this code to log in outlook mail account ?

Comment: Try making an app password. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56900442/how-to-connect-outlook-mail-server-which-uses-multi-factor-authentication-using) for more.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.